# Can't get java to round 24.9999 properly, rounds to 8.?

Tags: java

I'm learning java and have a bit of code I am trying to write that should round 24.9999999 to 25. Instead, it goes to 8.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class RadiusOfCircle
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner kbInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is the area? _");
        double area = kbInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Radius of your circle is " + Math.sqrt( area / Math.PI));

        double radius = Math.sqrt( area / Math.PI);
        System.out.println("\nChecking your work now...\n   area = pi*(r^2)\n   " + area + " = 3.14 * (" + radius + ")^2");
        double radiusSqrd = Math.pow(radius, 2);
        System.out.println("   " + area + " = 3.14 * " + radiusSqrd);
        System.out.println("   " + area + " = " + Math.PI * radiusSqrd);
        System.out.println(area + " = " + (Math.round(radiusSqrd)));
        System.out.println("Are the two values the same? \nIf yes, your code is correct! \nIf no, try again!");
    }
}
```

Also, when it asks for keyboard input of what the area is, I put in 25.

This is the output:

```
What is the area? _25
Radius of your circle is 2.8209479177387813

Checking your work now...
   area = pi*(r^2)
   25.0 = 3.14 * (2.8209479177387813)^2
   25.0 = 3.14 * 7.957747154594766
   25.0 = 24.999999999999996
25.0 = 8
Are the two values the same? 
If yes, your code is correct! 
If no, try again!
```

Comment: I hope 24.anything never "properly" rounds to 8 :-)

Comment: This would have been a good time to use the debugger to debug your code so you can see what each line is doing. ;)

Comment: I found Peter's comment most helpful for a student.  I would have directed the student's attention to this line of output:  "   25.0 = 24.999999999999996"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.out.println("   " + area + " = " + Math.PI * radiusSqrd);
System.out.println(area + " = " + (Math.round(radiusSqrd)));
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
double value = Math.PI * radiusSqrd;
System.out.println("   " + area + " = " +value );
System.out.println(area + " = " + (Math.round(value )));
```

Comment: yes, i didn't realize that i was rounding the wrong value. i changed it so that last part is math.round(Math.PI * radiusSqrd)

Comment: Since I was first I should get the green tick :P

Answer (score 11):

You're rounding `radiusSquared` only, rather than `Math.PI * radiusSquared`. Fixing that should get the result you expect.

Comment: +1.  Also you should accept the answer as correct :) Welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 2):

You omitted to multiply by `PI`:

```
System.out.println(area + " = " + Math.round(Math.PI * radiusSqrd));
```

Executing this gives the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

`float` and `double` were designed for engineering problems, which have large positive powers of 10.. they cannot express negative powers of 10 accurately. In such cases use `BigDecimal`.

Run this simple code from Joshua Bloch's book Effective Java to get a sense of the extend of inaccuracy when dealing with negative powers and using `double` to store them. The answer should acutally be `zero`, but turns out to be something else entirely!

```
double funds = 1.00; 
int itemsBought = 0; 
for (double price = .10; funds >= price; price += .10) { 
  funds -= price; 
  itemsBought++; 
} 
System.out.println(itemsBought + ” items bought.”); 
System.out.println(“Change: $” + funds); 
}
```

Comment: Buy the book Effective Java 2 and put it under your pillow after you've finished learning the basics

Comment: FYI IEEE-754 also specifies Base-10 implementations (the `float` and `double` found in Java and most processors/languages are Base-2 though). The first sentence of this reply is ... confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "accurate" math in Java, you should use the BigDecimal class, rather than either of the built-in floating point primitive types.  double and float are *always* going to have issues like this, due to the nature of floating point arithmetic.

Please note that the recommended constructor for BigDecimal uses a String, not any of the numeric types.  Since you are getting input from the console, this should be easy to implement.

Comment: haven't learned that yet, but thanks for the tip. i was wondering why it would just stop the decimal places after a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
    double d = 10.938;

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d);
    bd = bd.setScale(0,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(bd);

    bd = new BigDecimal(d);
    bd = bd.setScale(1,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);        
    System.out.println(bd);

    bd = new BigDecimal(d);        
    bd = bd.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(bd);
```

or like this:

```
    double d = 10.938;

    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#");        
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(d));

    decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(d));

    decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(d));
```